# XML/XSLT: pulling information from two different nodes from XML in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

So I have this code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
<Row>
    <Cell Borders="#ffffff">
      <xsl:attribute name="Background">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">#CCCCFF</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#FFFFFF</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <Paddings Left="5" Right="5" Top="2" Bottom="2"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//queries/query/selection/dataItem">
      <Text Style="TableContent">                                               
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>                                                                                        
      </Text>
      </xsl:for-each>   
    </Cell>
    <Cell Borders="#ffffff">
      <xsl:attribute name="Background">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">#CCCCFF</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#FFFFFF</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <Paddings Left="5" Right="5" Top="2" Bottom="2"/>
      <Text Style="TableContent">
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="qi">
        <xsl:value-of select="qi"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <Text>N/A</Text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose> 
      </Text>
    </Cell>
</Row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am trying to pull information from an XML, however the information is in two different nodes, with two different XPATH. Also I need to match the information from one node, i.e. name. to another node located under a different location, with a different XPATH. is there a way to go through each name in the node and match it to the information found in another node all in the same XML??

EDIT
[Added link to original XML](http://pastebin.com/RrU8mR7R)

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, this certainly sounds possible, possibly using an xsl:key, for example, but we would really need to see a sample of your XML to give more specific help. If you edit your question to show a meaningful sample of XML, that would help alot. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to provide the link for the xml before but i have added the link now. Hopefully it helps a little. I am trying to grab the lineage information and match the name node under lineage with the expression under the dataItem node in query.

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide an XML document (small) in the questio. Please, also provide the exact wanted result and explain any requirements that the transformation must implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access **dataItem** elements where the **expression** element matches the **name** element of the current item.

In this case, you can create a key to look up **dataItem** records by their **expression** value

```
<xsl:key name="dataItems" match="dataItem" use="expression" />
```

Then, instead of looping through all **dataItem** records like you are doing currently...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//queries/query/selection/dataItem">
```

You can replace this line to simply use the key to iterate over only those dataItems with the relevant value

```
 <xsl:for-each select="key('dataItems', name)">
```

Here, **name** is the name element under the current **item** element on which you are currently positioned.

Here is some fuller XSLT, to show the **xsl:key** element in context

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="dataItems" match="dataItem" use="expression"/>

   <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="lineage"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="lineage">
      <xsl:for-each select="item">
         <Row>
            <Cell Borders="#ffffff">
               <xsl:attribute name="Background">
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">#CCCCFF</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#FFFFFF</xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <Paddings Left="5" Right="5" Top="2" Bottom="2"/>
               <xsl:for-each select="key('dataItems', name)">
                  <Text Style="TableContent">
                     <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                  </Text>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </Cell>
            <Cell Borders="#ffffff">
               <xsl:attribute name="Background">
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">#CCCCFF</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">#FFFFFF</xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <Paddings Left="5" Right="5" Top="2" Bottom="2"/>
               <Text Style="TableContent">
                  <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="qi">
                        <xsl:value-of select="qi"/>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Text>N/A</Text>
                     </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
               </Text>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried using the key in my xslt and I got this error, "'xsl:key' is not a recognized extension element". Also would i have to declare the key above the template or inside of the Cell node?

Comment: xsl:key should be a stand XSLT function. It should go outside of any xsl:template.

Comment: I edited my code the way you had it and it still errors out. I believe it might be because I am using stylesheet version 2.0? could that be a possibility? I have looked up numerous examples and they all seem to using xsl stylesheet 1.0.

Comment: Just FYI this was throwing me off: 
   <xsl:template match="lineage">
when I took that template statement out. It worked fine. Thank you very much Tim C.

Comment: Is it possible for me to retrieve the query name from which each dataitem -> expression came from?? I was trying to use a for-each statement. Basically a for-each dataItem name retrieved, I want to be able to get the query name also. is that possible? @Tim

Comment: I think, if I understand this correctly, you need first need to create a variable within your first for-each item, like this `<xsl:variable name="item" select="." />`. Then, within your for-each dataItem you can get the value of any field of the item like so: `<xsl:value-of select="$item/ns"/>`

Comment: Thanks Tim. I was able to use another key to get the query name. However, the one issue I am having is that I have dataItems that are being repeated. I tried using the following code:

Comment: <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="dataItems">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dataitems[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dataitems', @name)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: If you are having different issues to the one above, you should really think about starting a new question. Thanks!